# Scheduling Facebook Messages

Tags: facebook

I want to be able to schedule a message with a video so that my friend/relative can receive it in a similar fashion to a greeting card.

I know it is possible to schedule wall posts, fan page updates and Twitter (which can update Facebook). Is it possible to schedule a Facebook message with a video (or at least a picture) ? If yes how ? If no, what are the possible reasons and steps to try to make it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here is a method that was not available when you had asked this question:

Step 1: Create a Facebook email id.

Step 2: Go to Gmail>Settings>Accounts and Imports; in the **Send Mail As** section, add the Facebook email Id.

Step 3: Download and Install the **Boomerang For Gmail** Google Chrome Extension from www.boomeranggmail.com

Step 4: Schedule a message to be sent from your Gmail account in the name of the Facebook account to your family members (they should have signed up for Facebook email too).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good one for you - "Message In a Bottle".

http://apps.facebook.com/messageinbottle/

It should be exactly what you're looking for, essentially a "time capsule" application that allows you to send messages in the future - far into the future, too.

I can't recall if it delivers the message immediately, showing the subject, but protecting the contents, but hopefully it's what you had in mind.  You can try sending a message to yourself first.

Comment: **Does not work anymore.** Error message: "This application does not yet support secure browsing (HTTPS)."

Answer (score 0):

Recently we  made the application in Facebook, you can schedule greetings.

http://apps.facebook.com/greetingscheduler/

Give it a try, Its really nice app to use.

Comment: **Does not work anymore.** The server [www.schedulegreetings.com](http://www.schedulegreetings.com) cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Jarvee.com](http://jarvee.com?ap_id=seo&c_id=qa) to schedule Facebook messages to friends, family or even potential clients for my business.

It doesn't allow sending messages with pictures or videos but it works well with text messages.

Answer (score -1):

I use [socinator](https://www.socinator.com) for this purpose. It can schedule FB messages and also supports images and videos.